# Join table or create column for few rows

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I have a table `main` which contains different types of information.

we call type `A` `B` `C` `D` and `E`, for each one I have same 'details' stored in N columns.

**The problem:** But I need a new 'detail' only for type `E`

So, I thinks in two solutions

> (1) Create a column `new_detail` in table

- this will put `NULL` in types `A` `B` `C` `D`.
- type `E` is 1 per 10 000 rows, and `main` table have about 50 000 rows/year

> (2) Create a `new_table` with `main_id` `new_detail` and join it

- The join is only required when `E` type is in use (not always)

*Which method is a best practice and why? other solutions are accepted*

Comment: What is the meaning of a column having a type in your understanding?

Comment: oh sorry, language problems, that is data type, anything, think of as t-shirts, pants, hats and shoes. (how can I be more explanatory?)

Comment: Can you please show some data to describe what you have in mind.  I don't follow your current question.

Comment: if I explain the complete problem you are more confused, `(referring to the previous comment)`
each clothing for example has color, size, gender, but I need only shoes have type of sole

Comment: MySQL doesn't implement check constraints, so other than possibly a trigger there isn't any way to control what gets inserted into your table at the database level.  But can't your app simply check the types?

Comment: The problem is how to save the data, because now there is a new detail to save, the database was not designed for that, then create a new column for this new feature, or create a table apart for this feature, the solution is looks obvious, but being so little data that occupy this feature makes me doubt.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, but I'll wager that your problem is not so complex or difficult that standard RDBMS logic cannot handle.  Again, for the second time, show us some data and maybe you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your main problem is about the memory that can be used to generate new columns but don't be afraid to generate new columns, with a simple experiment it is shown that nulls do not occupy memory, apart from the information of the column.

The first solution I think is easier and cleaner, the second is more about the normalization of data that is not the case, just more properties.

---

First create a **table_a** with a lot of trash

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#Execute this a lot of times.
INSERT INTO `table_a` (value) VALUES ('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum'),('Lorem Ipsum');
```

I created 1980 rows and this has a size of 9+176 KB

[image: table_a_size]

Then create a **table_b** cloning the **table_a** but with multiple `NULL` columns

```
CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `a` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `c` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `d` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `e` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `f` varchar(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table_b` (value) SELECT value FROM `table_a`;
```

Like table_a, it has the same size but the head is larger. (13+176 KB)
[image: table_b_size_1]

But we copy the `value` column to `a` we get this.

```
 UPDATE table_b SET A=value;
```

[image: table_b_size_2]

If the data is `NULL` this not affect

Answer (score -1):

Method 2 is better: create a separate table to store the data associated with the "E" types. This is a fundamental principle of [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).